# Securities Software

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

I was wondering if anybody had any good ideas for managing a Securities database?  Currently the db is an Access db and there is talk of migrating it to a SQL server.  However, does anybody know of a good front-end UI that would help non-technical people query the SQL server that holds Securities information?

Comment: Securities as in financial products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are already UI forms in Access, you can keep them. Move the data to SQL-Server and have the Access database link to the tables in SQL-Server. Of course, you could also build a web-based interface, a desktop app, etc...

Comment: this was my exact response to this problem.  however, my boss does not want to use Access (seriously, don't ask me why not).  any other suggestions?  any web enabled things i can use to query my SQL db?

Comment: @user102398: There's probably lots of good reasons why he doesn't. In my experience this technique has crappy performance. But the advantage is you can save all your UI stuff, and if you've built a lot of complicated forms with VBA code behind them, this is a significant point. Other UI options... I'm not really sure, you might have to start building similar functionality as a custom app that has the same functionality as the Access forms. Not fun, I know, but I don't know of any tools that will get you there faster. :( Or maybe look into other reporting tools?

Comment: There is nothing that has the same flexibility as Access. Why does your boss want to avoid Access? PHB syndrome, or are there some actual reasons involved?

Comment: If your experience is that performance is poor with a server back end and an Access front end, it probably indicates that you don't know how to optimize an Access app for a client/server back end. In general, most things will work fine after upsizing, but a few things will be bottlenecks, and the usual approach is to move those server-side to avoid the problem.

Comment: i 100% agree -- i think for all intensive purposes, optimizing Access set up with this db would have taken care of the problem.  However, i think it's simply a "i don't know access that well, so we need to use another solution" issue.  :S  i'm completely at a loss for what program/app is out there to help manage this db

Comment: @user102398: this becomes a different kind of issue then. If you could create this optimized Access front-end and show that it really *really* works, would the boss be cool with it then? Other than that, I'm not sure what alternate reporting tools you could use (asusming that the users just need to query/report).